# find which types from given dll are used in my solution

Tags: c#, .net, resharper

I've got sulution which uses external dll. What is the best way to list all types from that external dll used in my solution?

Maybe resharper has got any option which may suport this?

Comment: If nothing else works, you can always remove the reference to the DLL and see where you get errors :o)

Comment: I'd suggest NDepend for this rather than R#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

References are always used within a project. To find the types used from that assembly just open the context menu of that referenced assembly under `References` of your project and select `Find Code Dependent on Module`

[image]

If you want to see which types are used, you can group them in the result window by type:
[image]

If that DLL is referenced within multiple projects you would have to do that on every project. I don't think there is a way to do that an a solution level.

Comment: to much work cause for example Ive 1000 usages of code dependent on module and I ve to look at each one just to see at the end that one class is not used - i would prefer to have list of used types from given dll